# How to create a link for calendar in blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Building a calendar application with blazor (webserver) and looking for a way to create an ICS files.

I look at iCals but it only support ASP.net core but not blazor. Any library i should look for that is more current

I look at the following solution here: https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js/

But when i applied it

```
private async Task addToCalendar()
 {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addCalendar", "Demo Event", "This is thirty minute event", "Nome, AK", "8/7/2013 5:30 pm", "8/7/2013 6:00 pm");
 }
```

I get filename does not exist.

Comment: *it only support ASP.net core but not blazor* - that doesn't make any sense, especially for SSB

Comment: Any current solution for to create an ICS files that could be used for blazor?